# Writting to CSV file using LINQtoCSV, puts CR LF at the end of the file

Tags: c#, forms, csv, linqtocsv

I'm writting wifi data (ID and password) into a CSV file using the LINQtoCSV NuGet and I'm getting at the end of the line Carriage return (red ractangle on the picture).

[image]

Could the .TrimEnd('\r', '\n') method help me in some way?

My code:

```
var listSettings = new List<Wifi_User>
{
    new Wifi_User
    {
        SSID = "id_112",
        password = "guest"
    }
};

var csvFileDescription = new CsvFileDescription
{
    FirstLineHasColumnNames = true,
    SeparatorChar = ','
};

var csvContext = new CsvContext();
csvContext.Write(listSettings,"D:\\WIFICRED.CSV",csvFileDescription);
```

Comment: Since this library probably uses a StreamWriter / TextWriter derived class, you could initialize your own and set the `TextWriter.NewLine` to something else than the default `"\r\n"` in Windows -- Not clear why you would replace both Carriage Return and Line Feed, though. A text editor would show a single line of everything you have stored. Reading back would also be problematic. What problem are you trying to solve?

Comment: Hi, thx for the comment. Yeah like you said, this doesn't make sense, true. I just need to get rid of the last one like I marked on the image, because the Iot modul detects the Carriage Return and won't connect to the WiFi.

Comment: You should send the package compressed (GZipStream or similar or a compressed file or a base64 string). Stripping the line terminators is bound to cause grief -- Not clear what causes a problem, though

Comment: The newline is "end of record" so without it, the last record, and therefore the file, is incomplete. You really *don't* want to omit it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Found a solution... If there is a CR/LF at the end of the line I'm using this syntax...

```
string myFileData;
myFileData = File.ReadAllText(@"D:\CsvFile.csv");
if (myFileData.EndsWith(Environment.NewLine))
{
    File.WriteAllText(@"D:\CsvFile.csv", myFileData.TrimEnd(Environment.NewLine.ToCharArray())); 
}
```